# Thymeleaf - th:method="delete/put" leads to: Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I use Spring Boot v2.7.0, installed from "start.spring.io" and from there I installed Thymeleaf, and as I searched in the parent-pom I found out that:
thymeleaf-spring5 (v3.0.15.RELEASE), thymeleaf-extras-java8time (v3.0.4.RELEASE)

Lately, I needed to apply the pattern **<form th:method="put/delete".../>**.
After googling in verious places, I found the solution, which was reffered in the book as well:
"**Taming Thymeleaf Practical Guide to building a web application with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf - Wim Deblauwe**"
which is the top/excellent books of Thymeleaf, and from which I learn Thymeleaf.
Acoording to these, I did:

**Step 1:**

Added this property in **application.properties**:

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true
```

and I tried it in the **application.yaml** (as a 2nd solution, because the previous did not work), like this way:

```
spring:
  mvc:
    hiddenmethod:
      filter:
        enabled: true
```

**Step 2:**

I used:

```
<form th:method="put".../>
<form th:method="delete".../>
```

**Step 3:**

Finally I used the: "**@PutMapping**, **@DeleteMapping**" in my controller handler methods.

The result was the error message:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:253)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:442)
```

After googling I found this solution, to add the needed bean by myself with the following way, which **DID WORKED:**

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<HiddenHttpMethodFilter> hiddenHttpMethodFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<HiddenHttpMethodFilter> filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new HiddenHttpMethodFilter());
    filterRegistrationBean.setUrlPatterns(Arrays.asList("/*"));
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

I wonder why this configuration "spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true", does not add the needed bean in my case, and I have to add it by myself.

Anyone can help me on this, please?
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did a test myself and this worked fine.

1. Create a new project on start.spring.io selecting Spring Boot 2.7.1 with dependencies Spring Web and Thymeleaf
2. Create a controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RequestMapping
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("formData", new TestFormData());
        return "index";
    }

    @PutMapping
    public String doPut(@ModelAttribute("formData") TestFormData formData) {
        System.out.println("formData.getSomeString() = " + formData.getSomeString());
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

With this form data class:

```
public class TestFormData {
    private String someString;

    public String getSomeString() {
        return someString;
    }

    public void setSomeString(String someString) {
        this.someString = someString;
    }
}
```

3. Create an `index.html` file in `src/main/resources/templates`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form th:action="@{/}" th:method="put" th:object="${formData}">
    <input th:field="*{someString}">
    <button>Save</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

4. Update `application.properties` to contain:

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true
```

5. Start the application and go to http://localhost:8080 and enter something in the input field. When pressing save, it is printed to the console, showing that the `@PutMapping` works.

Comment: Hello @Deblauwe, sir. Thank you for your reply. I tried your steps in a new project. It works fine to me also. I changed the properties to yaml, and the "new" operator you used in Component/Autowired. Works nice as well. I accept it as solution, but I need to find in my project's code/configuration, what breaks this funtionality. As soon as I find out, what went wrong in my case, I will right it down here in a comment in your reply. Thanks a lot again

Comment: After some changes, I found out what causes the problem, but I don't know why... In spring boot I came from "simple" spring mvc. There my project has in IntelliJ "webapp/WEB-INF", and there in the "webapp/WEB-INF/views" I put my thymeleaf views. For that reason, I put code in the WebConfig to resolve the: Bean public ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
/*...*/
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
resolver.setSuffix(".html");
/*...*/}  I tried to make the stucture in the demo project you made @Deblauwe, like my straucture I wrote before, I this gave me: "POST is not supported"

Comment: I am studding to understand why this structure "webapp/WEB-INF/views", cuses this problem